# SegWit Version - is there a proposal for new versions?

Tags: segregated-witness

I can see transactions with version 0.
Are there any other versions of SegWit proposed or in existence?

Answer (score 3):

BIP-114 which was published a while ago comes to mind :
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0114.mediawiki

Answer (score 3):

[Taproot](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) is implemented as SegWit version 1.

Another proposed feature that would most likely be implemented as a new SegWit version is cross-input signature aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

The introduction of [Schnorr signatures](https://github.com/sipa/bips/blob/bip-schnorr/bip-schnorr.mediawiki) would require a new script version.